# Django: many-to-many ordering

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have many-to-many server to network through ip relationship:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    networks = models.ManyToManyField(Network, through='Ip')

class Network(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Ip(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server) # initially this line was missing
```

I render it to table:

```
Hostname | Network 1 | Network 2
==============================
server 1 | 1.1.1.10  | 5.5.5.100
server 2 | 1.1.1.15  | 5.5.5.20
```

I need this table to be ordered by column. Ordering by column is easy:

```
Server.objecs.all().order_by('hostname')
```

How can I do the same with two other columns? E.g. if table is ordered by "Network 2" column, order will be "server 2, server 1".

EDIT: Corrected the code.

Comment: But here `Network1` and `Network2` are not *columns*. This is a separate table. An m2m is even fetched by other querie(s).

Comment: Yes, its not columns. But I have a view, which renders this table, and there's columns for each network. And I want sort this table by ip in certain network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order many-to-many table in **Django**, You need intermediate model (First of all). You IP model is not good (IMO). Not finished at all.

```
class Server(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    networks = models.ManyToManyField(to='Network', through='ServerNetworkRel')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'server'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname

class Network(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'network'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ServerNetworkRel(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    server = models.ForeignKey(to=Server, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    network = models.ForeignKey(to=Network, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'server_network_rel'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.server.hostname + ' ' + self.network.name
```

and perform sql query now,,,

```
filtered_rows = ServerNetworkRel.objects.select_related('server', 'network').order_by('network__field') # This returns ServerNetworkRel which has already made INNER JOIN On (Server and Network)

for row in filtered_rows:
    print(row.server) # returns Server instance
    print(row.network) # returns Network instance
```

Comment: The actual code has server field. I'll correct the question. But problem is that I don't need an ordered ip queryset, I need an ordered server queryset with different order depending on choosen network.

Comment: Your rendered table is wrong, Network1 | Network2 ... We do not have this fields... Your intermediate Model (Many2Many table) is IP with ip | server_id | network_id

Comment: This is how I need it to be rendered. Maybe there's a misunderstanding, I render it  in one of my views. And I want it to be sorted by certain column.

Comment: Why do you need class Network(models.Model): pass ?

Use just Server model with fields (hostname, ip). What's is idea of Network with field (name) ?

Comment: Because there's different networks with different masks, gateways, purposes. And it's not about networks and ips, it's about the principle. What if we have persons and groups, each person has different role in each group. How do we sort list of this persons by their roles? What if we have companies which have many accounts in many banks?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it will be more helpful. Test carefully.

Comment: Am I getting it right? It's getting list of ips, which related to given network and server? It's still not quite the thing that I needed, but thanks anyway.

Comment: In reality it returns collection of server_instance + network_instance + ip field
for row in filtered_rows:
    py_tuple = (row.server.hostname, row.network.name, row.ip)
    print(py_tuple)

Answer (score 0):

All right, this is how I managed to do it:

At first we need to convert queryset to list:

```
qs = Server.objects.all()
net = Network.objects.get(pk=1) # we gonna sort servers by ip in this network
list = [x for x in qs]
```

or

```
list = list(qs)
```

then we can sort this list. Not all servers has ip in every network, so we need to check if ip is not None:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: x.ip_set.filter(network=net).first().ip if x.ip_set.filter(network=net).first() is not None else 0)
```